# Apache Batik Java Swing, SVG not loading in the right way

Tags: java, swing, awt, batik

So, I am doing a School project where we have to use Java Swing to create a game based on Travle, for the image of the map, I considered using a svg file so i could divide it by the layers, I then used Apache Batik to visualize it, but it doesn't work properly, [This is the program running 3 different times, sometimes the map is right, sometime is small and other times it is too big.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlEz9.png)

Does anyone know why this happens?

`canvas = new JSVGCanvas(); canvas.setURI(".\\src\\img\\mappa.svg");`

This is the only thing about this i wrote in the code.

The names on the right are generated by random, so i thought that could be the problem, but even with them not being random, it stills happen.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I suggest that you read [ask]. Then [edit] your question and post a [mcve]. Also post a link to the image file. Then I can reproduce your problem and subsequently debug it to try and help you fix the problem. What Java version are you using? What version of [Batik](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) are you using? What platform are you on?